# How to conditionally apply style to a Kendo UI grid 'row'?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the below Kendo UI gridOptions for my angular page:

```
ctrl.gridOptions = {
        rowTemplate: '<tr data-uid="#: uid #" class="#:ApprovalStatus=\'Approved\'? \"approved\" : \"unapporved\"#"></tr>',
        //rowTemplate: '<tr data-uid="#: uid #" class="#:ApprovalStatus=\'Approved\' ? \'approved\' : \'unapproved\' #"><td>#:ProcessName #</td><td>#:TradeAmount #</td><td>#:AQRID #</td><td>#:ApprovalStatus #</td></tr>',
        dataSource: {
            type: 'json',
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    DataSvc.getTradesData().then(function (response) {
                        options.success(response.data);

                    }, function (response) {
                        alert('something went wrong')
                        console.log(status);
                    });
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        IsChecked: { type: "boolean" },
                        ProcessName: { type: "string" },
                        TradeAmount: { type: "number" },
                        ApprovalStatus: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        selectable: "row",
        sortable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "IsChecked", width: "30px", title: " ", template: '<input ng-disabled="dataItem.ApprovalStatus" ng-model="dataItem.IsChecked" type="checkbox" />', filterable: false, headerTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-click="ctrl.checkAllTrades()" ng-model="ctrl.tradesChecked">' },
            { field: "ProcessName", title: "Process Name", width: "190px", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false, template: processNameDropDownEditor } }, template: '<a style="font-size: x-normal;" href="#=Link#">{{dataItem.ProcessName}}</a>', attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" } },
            { field: "TradeAmount", title: "Trade Amount", width: "120px", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false } } },
            { field: "ApprovalStatus", title: "Approval Status", width: "150px", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false, template: approvalStatusDropDownEditor } } }
        ],
        filterable: { mode: "row" },
        height: 550,
    };
```

The  approved & unapproved styles are defined as below:

```
.approved {
        background-color: green;
    }

.unapproved{
        background-color: red;
    }
```

So the problem is that when I apply the row template the grid is rendered empty. And when I apply the commented rowTemplate, then the grid is render with the rows, but only the 'approved' style is applied as shown below:

[image]

How can I apply the style to each TR based on the condition on a data bound field? Also when the commented rowTemplate is applied the columns are not displayed properly, how can we fix that ?

**UPDATE:**

The below rowTemplate helped be fix the background-color problem. But still unable to fix the column alignment issue.

```
rowTemplate: '<tr data-uid="#: uid #" ng-class="{approved: \'#:ApprovalStatus#\' ==\'Approved\', unapproved: \'#:ApprovalStatus#\' ==\'Unapproved\'}"><td>#:ProcessName #</td><td>#:Account #</td><td>#:AQRID #</td><td>#:ApprovalStatus #</td></tr>',
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ng-class` directive here

```
rowTemplate: '<tr data-uid="#: uid #" ng-class="{approved : #:ApprovalStatus# ==\'Approved\', unapporved: #:ApprovalStatus# !=\'Approved\'></tr>'
```

Comment: thanks, but I have to make some change to the above code to make it work. I have update the question with the new piece of code. However, the other problem of columns not aligning themselves with the headers is still there. Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: @Lucifer try to apply some css classes on each td..you might need to fix the width of column

Comment: @@pankajparkar, are you telling me to do away with the rowTemplate and apply a ng-class on each column ?? There shouldn't be a need of it if there exists a straight forward way to apply a style on the TR. I have around 10 columns in my actual grid, and i'll have to apply ng-class on each of them.

Comment: @Lucifer no I'm telling you to apply css rule on each of them..like here you could do `.approved tr>td, .unapporved tr>td{ /*css here*/ }` you have controller on each row using `approved ` & `unapporved` use css rule by thinking of them

Comment: could you please give me a sample for one of the Kendo UI column definition.

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/FcWBQ/) ,
Hope it help....

Comment: I did reference that link...but it needs the TD's too...and if we specify the TD's in the rowTemplate then the headers alignment is disturbed.